# how to deploy standalone java applications (jar's) to bluemix?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

There are lots of instructions online for deploying web applications (war files) to Bluemix, but I couldn't find any documentation on deployment of standalone java applications, that are run similar to the following:

`java -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: [http://archive.thoughtsoncloud.com/2014/10/create-deploy-stand-alone-java-application-ibm-bluemix/](http://archive.thoughtsoncloud.com/2014/10/create-deploy-stand-alone-java-application-ibm-bluemix/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Runnable jar support was recently just introduced so you can do this.

All you need to do is have a jar that has a `Main` method and it will run.

1. Create an empty directory and place your jar file in it.
2. Run `cf push myappname -p myjarname.jar` (replacing myappname with a name for your app)

**Note:**
If you jar doesn't listen for web traffic your push command should be what is below.  This allows the jar to start but not listen for web traffic.

`cf push myappname -p myjarname.jar --no-route`

Comment: If the app doesn't listen for web-traffic on an assigned port, I think you still need to push it with `--no-route`

Comment: Actually the Liberty buildpack in Bluemix supports Jar applications quite a while back. The doc need to be fixed.